# issue with validating confirm password field using vuelidate and vue 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vuelidate

I have a issue with confirm password field in vuelidate for vue 3. my requirement is to check confirm password with password field and send error if not matched. i used vuelidate next library for that. the password and confirm password fields checking correctly when user interacts with the input. but the problem is when a user type both password and confirm password fields correctly and again user change the password field validations are not working. it only works when user interacts the input.

these are my input fields how i used vuelidate

```
   <Password
    v-model.trim="v$.passwordConfirm.$model"
    :feedback="false"
    :class="{ 'p-invalid': v$.passwordConfirm.$error }"
    @blur="v$.passwordConfirm.$touch()"
    class="p-mb-1"
    placeholder="Confirm Password"
    toggleMask
    >
    </Password>
    <template
       v-for="(error, index) of v$.passwordConfirm.$errors"
       :key="index"
    >
      <span v-if="v$.passwordConfirm.$error" class="p-error">{{error.$message}}</span>
    </template>
```

and this is my validation methods

```
  passwordConfirm: {
    required: helpers.withMessage(
      "Confirm password cannot be empty. ",
      required
    ),
    sameAsPassword: helpers.withMessage(
      "Confirm password must be same as password you entered above.",
      sameAs(dataAsRefs.password)
    ),
    $lazy: true
  },
```